# Healpy: Rotate a mask together with the map in hp.ma() vs. separately produce different results?

Tags: rotation, mask, healpy

I would like to understand a bit better the behavior of rotate_map_pixel() in this particular case. Below I try to provide a minimal toy example:

```
map = hp.ma(hp.read_map(mapFile))
map.mask = np.logical_not(hp.read_map(maskFile))
rot = hp.Rotator(coord=['G','C'])
map = rot.rotate_map_pixel(map)
mask = hp.read_map(maskFile)
mask = rot.rotate_map_pixel(mask)
```

This produces a slightly different map.mask and mask. By "different", I mean

```
skycut = np.where(map.mask[obj_pix]==False))
```

and

```
skycut = np.where(mask[obj_pix]==1.)
```

or

```
skycut = np.where(np.isclose(mask[obj_pix],1.))
```

all produce different skycut. I'd guess this is due to the interpolation procedure?

If I wish to use the mask for selection purpose, what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

If you display the 2 masks, you can see that in one case the mask is a float, in the other case it is a boolean.

Now one case `healpy` fills the map with `UNSEEN` and then interpolation is handled by `HEALPix C++`. I don't know how internally HEALPix handles that.
In the other case we pass a map of 0 and 1 and HEALPix does the interpolation, but we don't trigger any special case of handling `UNSEEN` values.

See https://zonca.dev/2021/06/healpy-rotate-mask.html a full notebook investigating that.

I find out experimentally that if I round the mask with a number very close to 1 I find the same mask.

[image]

[image]